# SQL Server Procedure Affects Only One Row Of The Table (Instead All)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a simple procedure in SQL Server 2008 which should update the price of the products with `Year >= 2005` by 10%. My code is working but it only affects the row that `Year = 2005` not the other rows which for example `Year = 2009`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Update_Prices_by_10_Percent
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Years_Table 
    SET Price = Price + (Price * 0.1) 
    WHERE [Year] >= 2005;
END
GO
```

Data type of year is `INT`.

Using

```
SELECT * 
FROM Years_Table 
WHERE "Year" >= 2005
```

I get 4 results.

Comment: so you have Year column of datatype int?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Years_Table WHERE "Year" >= 2005` -- How many results? What is the data type of "Year"?

Comment: P.S. increase price by 10% = price * 1.1

Comment: @rs. I know, my comment was merely meant as an FYI

Comment: I would hope you wouldn't make a procedure like this. pass in the change amount and year as parameters and rename it something like: `Update_Prices`

Comment: well, if price column is integer and prices values up to 9 for years <>2009, you wouldn't notice any difference. Could you provide schema and data samples via sqlfiddle?